# Detect when a window opens in wnck python

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject, wnck

I am making a window tiling script using libwnck. I would like to detect when the user opens a new window in order to resize it. Here is the gist of my code so far:

```py
import gi

gi.require_version("Wnck", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Wnck

screen = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
screen.force_update()

# Here I resize all windows in the current workspace using
# window.set_geometry

# The script ends here however I'd like it to continue forever
# and detect a "window opened event"
```

From the documentation it looks like there are virtual methods like `do_window_opened` but I have no idea how to get it working in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working simple test code. Hope it can help you and is what you want.

```
import gi

gi.require_version('Wnck', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Wnck
from gi.repository import Gtk


def test_do_when_window_opened_simple():
    Gtk.init([])
    screen: Wnck.Screen = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
    screen.force_update()

    def do_window_opened(this_screen: Wnck.Screen, opened_window: Wnck.Window):
        print('hello')
        app: Wnck.Application = opened_window.get_application()
        app_name = app.get_name()
        print('app name -> ' + app_name)
        print('window name -> ' + opened_window.get_name())

    screen.connect('window-opened', do_window_opened)

    Gtk.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_do_when_window_opened_simple()
```

See also:

[Please check the first comment of this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/fxs1t8/video_as_a_wallpaper/)

[Please check the example of this link, it's written in C though](https://developer.gnome.org/libwnck/stable/getting-started.html#getting-started.examples.lazy-initialization)

**Note: the Wnck.Screen object has a function named 'do_window_opened', but it's not implemented. I received an error message 'gi.repository.GLib.GError: g-invoke-error-quark: Class WnckScreen doesn't implement window_opened (1)' when trying to call it.**